# How to create a new CSV row of data per X amount of strings in an array

Tags: ruby, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet from an array.

```
 #Loop through each .olpOffer (product listing) and gather content from various elements
 parse_page.css('.olpOffer').each do |a|
    if a.css('.olpSellerName img').empty?
        seller = a.css('.olpSellerName').text.strip 
    else
        seller = a.css('.olpSellerName img').attr('alt').value 
    end
    offer_price = a.css('.olpOfferPrice').text.strip
    prime = a.css('.supersaver').text.strip
    shipping_info = a.css('.olpShippingInfo').text.strip.squeeze(" ").gsub!(/(\n)/, '')
    condition = a.css('.olpCondition').text.strip
    fba = "FBA" unless a.css('.olpBadge').empty?

    #Push data from each product listing into array
    arr.push(seller,offer_price,prime,shipping_info,condition,fba)
  end
    #Need to make each product listing's data begin in new row [HELP!!]
    CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
        csv << ["Seller", "Price", "Prime", "Shipping", "Condition", "FBA"]

        end
    end
```

I need to reset the row that the array is writing to after the `"FBA"` column so that I don't end up with one huge row of data in row 2.

I can't figure out how to correlate each string to a specific column header. Should I not use an array?

Comment: Would you please remove the whole unrelated parsing code and provide the input you have as is?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed the array that I was feeding into my csv to create a new row after every 7 strings in the array. Here's how I did it:

arr = an array that has some given amount of strings, always divisible by 7

```
rows = arr.each_slice(7)
CSV.open("#{file_name}", "ab") do |csv|
   csv << [title, asin]
   rows.each do |row|
      csv << row
   end
end
```